# I need to create elements on the fly when going from one html document to another

Tags: javascript, html, css, element

I've got a web page document with three fields on it, which collect the information that the user inputs on them. When pressing a button which I also have created, I need to build some html elements in another web page (html file) depending on what the user inputs inside a numeric input numeric field. If the user enters "3" I need three buttons to be created. The same way, if they enter "5", I'll need five buttons to be created. Those buttons must be created on the blank page I have named "control.html"

I have tried mapping the correspondent function to the onclick event of a button I have called "CREATE". The function (which I have named "showConcept(conceptName)" has an alert inside which works properly). However, when I create a variable that stores the returning values of "document.createElement("H1")" for later adding that variable's value to the document itself, (document.appendChild(control)) the result is not as expected, since the whole page remains blank.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <link href="css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/funciones.js"></script>





</head>


<body>

    <fieldset>

        <legend>CREAR CONCEPTO</legend>




        <table>

            <tr>
                <td class="columnaEtiquetas"><label>NOMBRE: </label></td>
                <td class="columnaCampos"><input type="text" id="inpNombre" class="campos"></input>
                </td>
            </tr>



            <tr>
                <td class="columnaEtiquetas"><label>NÚMERO CUOTAS: </label></td>
                <td class="columnaCampos"><input type="number" id="inpNCuotas" class="campos"></input>
                </td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td class="columnaEtiquetas"><label>IMPORTE TOTAL: </label></td>
                <td class="columnaCampos"><input type="number" id="inpImpTotal" class="campos"></input>
                </td>
            </tr>



        </table>

        <section>


            <button id="botonCrear" onclick="crearNuevoConcepto()">CREAR</button>





        </section>



    </fieldset>





</body>


</html>
```

And here's the javascript code:

```
var concepto;
var nCuotas;
var importeTotal;
var restante;
var cuotas;

function cargarMenuOpciones() {

    this.document.location.href = "menuOpciones.html";



}

function irAConceptoNuevo() {

    document.location.href = "nuevo_concepto.html";


}


function crearNuevoConcepto() {


    concepto = $('#inpNombre').val();

    nCuotas = $('#inpNCuotas').val();

    importeTotal = $('#inpImpTotal').val();

    restante = importeTotal / nCuotas;

    cuotas = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < nCuotas; i++) {

        cuotas[i] = "Pendiente";

    }

    localStorage.setItem(concepto, JSON.stringify(cuotas));

    console.log(cuotas);


    mostrarConcepto(concepto);

}

function mostrarConcepto(nombreDelConcepto) {


    document.location.href = "control.html"

    var control = document.createElement("button");

    control.innerHTML("Financiación De" + concepto);

    document.appendChild(control);



}
```

The destination web page document remains blank. No error messages on the console.

Comment: Did you try creating elements on load event listener at destination web page?

Comment: Yes, I did. And it's very strange, because somehow it creates the elements before directing to that destination page. What it does is it creates the elements on the root page (they can be seen for a millisecond or so) and immediately loads up the destination web page, which is totally blank.